# AngularJS directive compile function receives DOM with markup language not resolved

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to create a directive to disable some UI elements based on the id. I'm creating the id dynamically inside a ng-repeat element.

To do that I'm using a directive. My problem is when the compile function is called the DOM still has markup and my id attribute looks like {{ iteration_object.id }} instead of "myObjectId"
Here is an example

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/psLkyofu/
```

I tried using link function instead of compile but I had the same problem.

Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Compile function of the directive gets called only once before scope is assigned for the directive.
Sequence of functions getting executed are as follows

1. compile
2. controller (scope is instantiated with controller)
3. pre link function (scope is available but children directives (if nested) are not yet compiled)
4. child directive's pre link
5. child directive's post link
6. post link function (scope is available and childrens directives are attached too. Considered as safe to manipulate the directive element with children. Because there is no fear of overwriting changes done in child directives by angular while executing link functions of those child directives.)

Link function is appropriate because it is called with scope as an argument.

I used link function and it worked 
Please check 
http://jsfiddle.net/psLkyofu/2/

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.directive('disableBasedOnCondition', function() {
return {
restrict : 'A',
link : function(scope,element, attr){
        var aElements = $(element).find('input');
    aElements.each(function(index, aElem) {
    console.log(aElem);
            var disabled = $(aElem).attr('id') === 'id2';
    if (disabled) {
        console.log('disabling element' + $(aElem).attr('id'))
        $(aElem).attr('ng-disabled', 'true');
    }
  })
}


  };

});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
$scope.name = 'Superhero';

  $scope.testValues = [
{ linkValue: 'test1', id: 'id1', label: "this is link 1"},
{ linkValue: 'test2', id: 'id2', label: "this is link 2"},
{ linkValue: 'test3', id: 'id3', label: "this is link 3"},
  ];

}
```